# could not cast value of type UIView to UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

i have made the game tic tac toe in swift .. the game is completed i am stuck on the last bit that when the user presses the play again button i want to set all the buttons images back to nil so that the user can start playing the game again. i used the tag property to set it back to nil. i coded this :

```
for i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ {
  var button = view.viewWithTag[i] as! UIButton
  button.setImage(nil, forState:.normal)
}
```

but it gives error

> could not cast value of type UIView to UIButton

Answer (score 5):

You need to check if the tag is configured right

```
   for var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ {
        let subview = view.viewWithTag(i)
        if subview?.isKindOfClass(UIButton) == true{
            let button = subview as! UIButton
            button.setImage(nil, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        }else{
            print("Tag \(i) is not configured right")
        }
    }
```

Also,like @**Dharmbir Choudhary** said

If you use tag to get button,**do not start with 0,because default tag is 0** it is easy to mess up.

Comment: You copied my last line :)

Comment: Sorry,did not see you words,I will update to note you said it first

Answer (score 4):

Use this bracket **()** instead of **[]** in `viewWithTag`.

```
    for i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ {

        var button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
        button.setImage(nil, forState:.normal)

    }
```

One more thing that you have to remember every subview in xib have tag 0(ByDefault) so you need to assign it from 1 to your button and start your for loop by i = 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is all right. The problem probably lies in that swift finds something else with zero tag, which can't be transformed to button, before it finds the first button. I would suggest you to go to the storyboard and in view move your zero tag button above all other buttons. This will allow swift to find your zero tag button first. I hope that helps! :)

Comment: That helped me out, I felt it's really tricky to use tag, cuz a lot of views may have the same tags accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

it should be viewWithTag(i) not viewWithTag[i]

Answer (score 1):

do this;

```
for i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ {
  if let button:UIButton = view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton {
     button.setImage(nil, forState:.normal)
  }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure that no any other view has the tag 0 to 8.

Answer (score 0):

This this confusion happens because of in your Screen there are other controls which also have **tag = 0** because of any control you put on screen it's by default tag is 0.

So, there are two solution for this problem :

1. change other controls tag to non-zero means set any tag value greater than 0 but not in 0 to 8.
2. Or change your button tag with 10 to 17 instead of 0 to 7

Use below code for option 1:

```
for var i:Int = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ {
    let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
    button.setImage(UIImage(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

and use below code for option 2:

```
for var i:Int = 10 ; i < 11 ; i++ {
    let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
    button.setImage(UIImage(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```